# java add new element to an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following code for the problem "Given a set of distinct integers, return all possible subsets. If `nums = [1,2,3]`, a solution is `[ [3], [1], [2], [1,2,3], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2], [] ]`."

```
public class Solution {
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets(int[] num) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    if(num == null || num.length == 0) {
        return result;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Arrays.sort(num);  
    subsetsHelper(result, list, num, 0);

    return result;
}


private void subsetsHelper(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result,
ArrayList<Integer> list, int[] num, int pos) {

    result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));

    for (int i = pos; i < num.length; i++) {
        list.add(num[i]);
        subsetsHelper(result, list, num, i + 1);
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

In `result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list))` why do I need to use `new ArrayList<Integer>(list))`? I know simply using `result.add(list)` would make the items in the result all the same, but I want to know the reason.

Comment: `result.add(list)` will basically get you the same result as `result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list))`....who said that you need to do `result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list))`? The only reason you'd want to go with `result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list))` is if you want to use a copy of the list for some reason. Please explain what you're trying to solve here.

Comment: @musical_coder please see the updated question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> new ArrayList<Integer>(list)
> ```

This is called a [copy constructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)#Copy_constructors), "*It is used to create a copy of an existing object of the same class.*"

Without the copy constructor each call to `result.add(list)` would add a reference to the *same list* repeatedly to `result`.  With the copy constructor a new list is created with the current values of `list`.  That way `subsetHelper()` can repeatedly modify `list` without also changing the lists already stored in `result`.

Make sure you understand how [Java passes around method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/113632); it's not complicated, but it is critical to being an effective Java programmer.